# .NET Core app hosting a REST endpoint in a Docker container throws "The prefix 'http://+:8020/' is not registered"

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I created my image using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyService.dll"]
```

I run the image mapping the port using the command:

```
docker run -p 8020:8020 --rm my-service
```

When the service tries to listen to port 8020, the following exception occurs:

```
HttpSysException: The prefix 'http://+:8020/' is not registered. Please run the following command as Administrator to register this prefix:
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8020/ user=User Manager\ContainerUser
See "Preregister URL prefixes on the server" on https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2127065 for more information.'
```

I tried adding the command given in this exception to the Dockerfile like so:

```
RUN netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8020/ user=User Manager\ContainerUser
```

but when I run the Docker build, it issues the following error:

```
The following command was not found: http add urlacl url=http://+:8020/ user=User Manager\ContainerUser.
The command 'cmd /S /C netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8020/ user=User Manager\ContainerUser' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The service's URL isn't configured by standard means such as environment variables or an appsettings file and I don't have control over this code. The service is configured in code as follows:

```
var webApplicationBuilder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
webApplicationBuilder.WebHost.UseHttpSys(options =>
{
    options.UrlPrefixes.Add(UrlPrefix.Create("http://+:8020"));
});
var webApplication = webApplicationBuilder.Build();
```

Any ideas how I might register the URL in the Docker image?

Comment: On what port is your webapp configured? You can set the port through many options. Try add ENV Urls=http://*:8020. Or add "Urls": "http://*:8020" in the appsettings.json.

Comment: The service is configured programmatically and does not use a standard configuration mechanism for determining the URL or port. I added the info about the configuration to the post.

Comment: Why are you using a plus sign in place of the wildcard `*`?

Comment: @fredrik No particular reason, but when changing to `*` I still get the same exception, except with `prefix 'http://*:8020/' is not registered`

Comment: UseHttpSys is Windows only and you're creating a Linux image. That's why the Windows-only command `netsh` can't be found. You need to either create a Windows image (which will also require a Windows docker host when you want to run it) or change the way you bind to the port to a Linux compatible way. I'd choose the latter option. But since you don't have control over the code, you might be forced to choose the former.

Comment: @HansKilian Thanks! That makes total sense! Will you please post that as an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: @HansKilian But it was not the ``netsh`` command that wos not found it was the ``http add ...``